# Can't get `count` from Asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js

I have the below code where `d3.json` is an asynchronous function. I am trying to run it in a loop while my `count` is equal to 100. My `while` loop stops after the first iteration, because the `count` is happening inside the asynchronous function, so I don't run it as many times as I should. How can I get the correct count so my `while` loop keeps executing while keeping the asynchronous trait?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        while(count == 100){
            console.log("first iteration");
            count = 0;
            d3.json("/api/messages/" + offset, function(error, json) {
                if (error) return console.warn(error);
                data = json;
                for(var i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++){
                    console.log(data.messages[i].date);
                    count++;
                    console.log(count);
                }
            });
            offset += 100;
        }
            var end = new Date().getTime();
            var time = end - start;
            console.log("Time to execute : " + time);
    });
});
```

EDIT: I'm trying for my calls to be as shown below. At each call you would check and make sure that there are 100 items(count) returned , and if not, you would stop the while loop

1. `/api/messages/0`
2. `/api/messages/100`
3. `/api/messages/200`
4. `/api/messages/300`
5. `/api/messages/400`
6. `/api/messages/500`
7. `/api/messages/600`

Comment: Are you trying to run `'/api/messages/1'`,  `'/api/messages/2'` ...  `'/api/messages/100'` ?

Comment: yes, but in increments of 100. So I'm pulling data from an api that only allows to pull in 100 elements at a time, and allows an offset at each request. So at each iteration I increase the offset by 100.

Comment: can you show a that appreviated list of expected url calls in the your question?

Comment: @Victory I have gone ahead and added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to chain this `ajax` calls until a certain cut-off point is reach (in this example offset is greater than max).

I have changed the `d3.json` call to `jQuery.getJSON` for this answer as its easier to debug on jsfiddle, but the concept is exactly the same. I also had to change the url for the request to use the jsfiddle debug api.

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
var offset = 0;
var maxOffset = 600;
var baseUrl = "/echo/json"; // change this to /api/messages in production

var callback = function(json) {
    console.log(json);

    console.log("current offset: " + offset);

    data = json;
    //  ... do something with data ...

    // increment the offset
    offset += 100;

    // don't run any more and return the execution time
    if (offset > maxOffset) {
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        var time = end - start;
        console.log("Time to execute : " + time);
        return; // don't run any more
    }

    // offset too small so run another getJSON call with our callback
    $.getJSON(baseUrl + "?" + offset, callback);
}

// when button is click, start the json call chain
$('button').click(function() {            
    // change the "?" to "/" in production
    $.getJSON(baseUrl + "?" + offset, callback);
});
```

If you need help translating this to your exact problem let me know.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/73fhLm1w/1/) is the jsfiddle.

Comment: in both the jsFiddle and my application, nothing happens when I press the button. I've set some debuggers in my application ( a `console.log("button pressed")` before the `$.getJSON(baseUrl + "?" + offset, callback);` in the button click, but that does not get printed either.

Comment: I wrapped the button clicked function with `$(document).ready` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

Create a function that accepts the relevant parameters: `start` offset, `increment`, and most importantly a `done` callback that should execute in the end.

This function contains a worker function, which will call the API, check the result and either call itself, or the `done` callback:

```
function fetchAllMessages(start, increment, done) {
    var messages = [];
    (function nextCall(offset) {
        d3.json("/api/messages/" + offset, function (error, data) {
            if (error) return done(error, messages);
            if (!data.messages) return done("unexpected response format", messages);

            messages.push.apply(messages, data.messages);
            if (data.messages.length === increment) {
                nextCall(offset + increment);
            } else {
                done(null, messages);
            }
        });
    })(start);
}
```

Now you can use it simply from your click event handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var start = Date.now();

        fetchAllMessages(0, 100, function (err, messages) {
            var end = Date.now();
            if (err) console.warn(err);
            console.log(messages);
            console.log("Time to execute : " + (start - end));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: When I include the code like this in my app and then debug, when I click the button it just skips over the `fetchAllMessages` function. I tried it your way, and using `$document.ready()` instead of just `$(functoin() {...`